Launching EC2 in UI vs Terraform, Not Authorized
I'm in class trying to spin up a VPC with 2 EC2 instances. Instead of doing it via the UI, I set up all the instances using Terraform. The problem is, I am able to spin up instances using the UI, but am unable to spin up instances using Terraform.
I understand that the issue lays with the fact my user ARN does not have the necessary permissions, but how come it's possible to create an instance using the UI using the same user?
The EC2.tf looks like:
resource "aws_instance" "mysql-db" {
    ami = "ami-0427090fd1714168b"
    instance_type = "t3.micro"
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.private.id
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.mysqldb.id]
    key_name = "vockey"

    tags = {
        Name = "mysql-db"
    }
    user_data = file("db-userdata.sh")
}

The error I get:
UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. User: arn:aws:iam::0:user/awsstudent is not authorized to perform:
 ec2:RunInstances on resource: arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:0:volume/* with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy

I understand that the issue lays with Terraform trying to create an EBS volume perhaps? Every EC2 gets an EBS volume on creation, and I am able to create an EC2 via the UI, but not in Terraform.
I tried to explicitly create an EBS volume inside the aws_instance configuration, however that did not work.

From AWS Documentation:

When a policy explicitly denies access because the policy contains a Deny statement, then AWS includes the phrase with an explicit deny in a type policy in the access denied error message

Explicitly being the keyword here, as your error message is stating that it is explicitly denying you.  You must have a policy attached to your IAM role that is explicitly denying ec2:RunInstances on the resource arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:0:volume/*.  It could be an overarching deny statement (i.e. denying you this permission on all EC2 resources), or specific to the resource.
Check your IAM role's policies.  I would also confirm that your Terraform is in fact using the same role as the one you use in the AWS web console.
